# How to get z bounds in this integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the volume in the region constrained by $z=1-y^2$; $z=0$; $z=4-2x$; $x=4$.

From microsoft mathematics I got this graph:
[image]

I understand that the region in the $xy$ plane is a square where $2 \le x \le 4$ and $-1 \le y \le 1$. I can also see that $z$ moves between the "floor" ($z=0$) and the parabolic cylinder $z=1-y^2$. However, if I say that $0 \le z \le 1-y^2$ I sense I'm missing the information given by the equation $z=4-2x$.

Could it be that, if I attempt to do it this way I have to calculate two integrals and add them up? Since $z$ seems to be going from $0$ to $1-y^2$ on a section of the region, then on the other part it seems to be going from $z=4-2x$ to $z=1-y^2$. Is this correct?

And then, if that is indeed correct, would it be right to do it this way to avoid adding up two integrals?

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1-y^2} \int_{2- \frac z 2}^4 dx dz dy$$

Comment: $x$ should depend on $z$ then. Use $(4-z)/2$ as lower bound.